# How to remove Optional(" ") and format date in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I have the following code:

`let dateToday = NSDate()`

I “pass” it to the Score View Controller via a function:

```
func saveScore(){

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let gameResult = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("SaveGame", inManagedObjectContext: appDelegate.managedObjectContext) as! SaveGame

    gameResult.datePlayed = dateToday
    // other data goes here

self.performSegueWithIdentifier(“scoreSegue", sender: self)
}
```

In the Score View Controller, I display it as:

`cell.textLabel?.text = "Date: \(game.datePlayed)`

However, I only get this line with the Optional(" ") line.

[pls check my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzCbT.png)

How do I remove the `Optional (" ")` and how do I format the date to:
`MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm (AM/PM)`?

Comment: Use `NSDateFormatter`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove the Optionnal("") indication you can use conditionnal binding like this :

```
if let date = game.datePlayed {
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Date: \(date)"
} else {
    //Here display something if no date is available
}
```

You could also force unwrap your variable with `game.datePlayed!` but I would recommend against it

To format your date to something readable, use `NSDateFormatter` like that:

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.LongStyle
formatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle

let dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(date)
```

You can change the `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` to suit your needs (choice between: `.ShortStyle`, `.MediumStyle`, `.LongStyle` and `.FullStyle`)

Additionaly you could use a custom date formatter like the following:

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm"

let dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(date)
```

Comment: How should I use the NSDateFormatter() Should I put it in the viewDidLoad as a function? I got the following error when I put it in my ViewController: `// expected declaration`

Comment: @pinkBlossoms7 you can just copy and paste this code where you need your date as a string. And then use dateString to populate a UILabel text for example